# Expanding reference searches in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, reference

When I click on a variable, object etc in eclipse and choose "References --> Project" from the context menu, I am presented with a list of methods which reference said object. However if a function has more than one reference the result is shown as:

```
functionName(signature) (x matches)
```

Double clicking on the result brings me to the first match, and there appears to be no way to locate the remaining matches. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the buttons with the up/down arrows in the search view, they will bring you to the previous/next search result, independent of the code structure, file location etc.

There is no way to further expand the tree of search results for a Java method.