# Expanding "find references" in eclipse (ADT)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

First of all this question is a (almost) duplicate of this question : 
[Expanding reference searches in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417687/expanding-reference-searches-in-eclipse)

The reason that i opened it is :

1. The original question has no solution
2. The question was asked 2 years ago and eclipse had many updates in this time.
3. I'm using Googles ADT, I find i hard to believe that Google released a product that millions of people using for development and annoyed by it.

And for the question:

In eclipse, (developing c/c++) when i look for references, i see the references in the find window in expanded mode : 
 [image]

But when i search in eclipse (developing android), i get the following un-expended and un-expendable mode :
[image]

I want to see the actual lines of code like in c/c++ and not just function names.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible with Java searches. The C/C++ tooling (aka, CDT) does it but that's a totally different implementation of searching.
It's documented as a feature request already, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318673

As mentioned in that request, if you do a file/plain-text search (via <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) then you get line-level matches in the Search view. Call Hierarchy also gives the Location panel which includes line-level details (though not presented in the tree like the CDT references search does).